# nginx upstream pass SSL client certificate

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

We already implemented the flow by means of this below approache and working good:

```
source machine -> acme.example.com(main nginx - region=US1) 
                             |
                           if (HTTP 429)  -> upstream to another nginx (region US2)
```

However, we enabled the mTLS handshake on the above, between source machine and acme.example.com, the mTLS handshake works fine, how do we also include mTLS handshake between main and upstream nginx ? I included this below in the main nginx and mTLS lines is also included in upstream nginx

```
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/root-ca/root.pem;
proxy_ssl_verify        optional;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert;
```